# can't sign android app lite version with same private key

Tags: android

i just signed my paid app and now i want to sign a lite version of it with the same private key. my problem now is that, am receiving this error:

jarsigner: unable to open jar file.

do i have to create another keystore for it? or is the problem coming from the fact that i am saving it as a different file name? what can i do? Thank you

Comment: Are you using the export tool in eclipse?

Comment: yes i am, but am not using the export signed application wizard that does all the signing for you. any problem i should know?

Comment: Why aren't you using the export signed application wizard?

Comment: was giving problems about my keystore . so i followed a tutorial on the web. thats the reason why, will try it again. so do i need another keystore for the lite version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is definitely not related to the fact that it is a lite version. I find it curious that the error message is `Jarsigner: Unable to open jar file.`

Some searching around leads me to believe you are making some typing error in your command (please revisit the steps found here http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp )

Also some other searching I did pointed to difficulties someone had with certain file names. Is your .APK name elaborate? Another instance of this problem I found ( http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.help/2005-09/msg01002.html ) was claimed to be solved by simplifying the name.

Also make sure you are actually pointing to the .APK. Try typing out full paths to the file if you're not already.

Answer (score 0):

I see an issue where i was using the full paths and it did not work, if you are having this problem, then just ensure that the .apk and the .keystore file is in the same destination. For my scenario I moved the apk to the root folder and run command and it worked. Hope this helps.