# jarsigner is unable to open jar file: NooYawk.apk .(NooYawk is App name)

Tags: android

I'm here signed my Map application with release key with the help of this link

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#cert

after generating debuging key next step is to generate Release map key by signing with the Certificate. i'm doing these steps which works fine but in end jarsigner is unable to find my NooYawk.apk file.

what should i do further.

> admins-Mac-mini:.android David$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore
> fureleasekey.keystore -alias fashion -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048
> -validity 10000

Next is:-

> admins-Mac-mini:~ David$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore
>
> maprelease.keystore -alias maps -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity
>
> 10000 Enter keystore password:   Re-enter new password:  What is your
>
> first and last name?   [Unknown]:  m What is the name of your
>
> organizational unit?   [Unknown]:  h What is the name of your
>
> organization?   [Unknown]:  k What is the name of your City or
>
> Locality?   [Unknown]:  le What is the name of your State or Province?
>
> [Unknown]:  we What is the two-letter country code for this unit?
>
> [Unknown]:  sd Is CN=m, OU=h, O=k, L=le, ST=we, C=sd correct?   [no]:
>
> yes

Next is:-

> Generating 2,048 bit RSA key pair and self-signed certificate
>
> (SHA1withRSA) with a validity of 10,000 days  for: CN=m, OU=h, O=k,
>
> L=le, ST=we, C=sd Enter key password for    (RETURN if same as
>
> keystore password):   Re-enter new password:  [Storing
>
> maprelease.keystore]

Next is:-

> admins-Mac-mini:~ David$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA
>
> -digestalg SHA1 -keystore maprelease.keystore NooYawk.apk maps Enter Passphrase for
>
> keystore:  jarsigner: unable to open jar file:
>
> NooYawk.apk

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please look at this similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228384/cant-sign-android-app-lite-version-with-same-private-key

Comment: This happens when the apk file name mismatch, alias mismatch, keystore & APK in different path, No write permission.

Answer (score 23):

Unless `NooYawk.apk` is in your current working directory, you need to supply a full path to the APK file.

Answer (score 2):

Cut the Keystore file from android folder to `build-->outputs-->apk` and paste it, then run the jarsigner command

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide a complete path to the directory of your apk file i.e /USER/DEVELOP/PATH_TO_APK (on a mac osx)

Answer (score 1):

One experience I had is I needed to run jarsigner in the same folder where not just the .apk file but also the related .ap_ and .apk.d files etc were present. So I copied the keystore to the bin output folder and ran jarsigner in that folder. Then things worked.

Answer (score -1):

You should try running the command in your apk path. Copy the unsigned keystore file to the apk path first.